# Truncate multiple paragraph inside div but keep html formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want paragraphs inside divs to be sliced after 100 characters from the paragraph character summary:

This is my code :

```js
 jQuery(function () {

        var minimized_elements = $('div.minimize');

        minimized_elements.each(function () {
            var t = $(this).text();
            if (t.length < 100) return;

            $(this).html(
                t.slice(0, 100) + '<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">Read More</a>' +
                '<span style="display:none;">' + t.slice(100, t.length) + ' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
            );

        });

        $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide().prev().hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        });

        $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="minimize">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pretium ultrices lacus non congue. Maecenas a augue suscipit, ullamcorper ex ut, maximus purus. In ac pellentesque justo. Proin metus sem, commodo vel aliquet blandit, varius a lacus. Aenean id turpis et leo congue fringilla. Nullam quis ultrices neque, nec pharetra diam. Integer et purus vitae massa pharetra gravida vitae malesuada lorem. Integer auctor dui eu posuere auctor.</p> 
 <p>Aliquam facilisis fermentum ex, quis interdum quam imperdiet eget. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla laoreet, purus in viverra varius, leo dolor consectetur urna, eget efficitur lacus odio sagittis massa. Mauris tincidunt vel augue nec eleifend. Integer blandit fringilla libero, eu volutpat justo aliquam vitae. Sed gravida sollicitudin urna in tincidunt. Integer eu velit ac enim dictum mollis. Integer condimentum egestas ante nec congue.</p> 
 </div>
```

There should be a paragraph break between .....auctor. and Aliquam......
Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `var minimized_elements = $('div.minimize p');`?  Otherwise, you're removing any html when you use `$(this).text()`.  If you use `$(this).html()` then you could potentially but a 'more' in the middle of a tag and mess up your page.  Otherwise, it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide an expected before and after for the HTML?

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry not to clear, the question is how to count character for slice text > 100 and display the original html when clicking "read more"..

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to generate a preview version as you are and toggle it and the original version. It would be more robust in cases where you have more complex markup, such as a list.

```js
 jQuery(function() {

  var minimized_elements = $('div.minimize');

  minimized_elements.each(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    if (t.length < 100) return;

    $(this).append('<a href="#" class="less">Show Less</a>')
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="original"></div>');

    $(this).append('<div class="intro"><p>' +
      t.slice(0, 100) +
      '<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">Read More</a></p></div>'
    );

    $(this).find('.original').hide();
  });

  $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.intro').hide().prev('.original').show();
  });

  $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.original').hide().next('.intro').show();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="minimize">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pretium ultrices lacus non congue. Maecenas a augue suscipit, ullamcorper ex ut, maximus purus. In ac pellentesque justo. Proin metus sem, commodo vel aliquet blandit, varius a lacus. Aenean id turpis et leo congue fringilla. Nullam quis ultrices neque, nec pharetra diam. Integer et purus vitae massa pharetra gravida vitae malesuada lorem. Integer auctor dui eu posuere auctor.</p> 
 <p>Aliquam facilisis fermentum ex, quis interdum quam imperdiet eget. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla laoreet, purus in viverra varius, leo dolor consectetur urna, eget efficitur lacus odio sagittis massa. Mauris tincidunt vel augue nec eleifend.</p> 
 </div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d9qpe8wz/)

Comment: yes yes, this is the so close from solution that i looking for, just little bit more..
try to change the slice text length to 500, and you will found "<p>Aliquam " still unite with above paragraph (before clicking read more)..
can you help this one?

Comment: try this one please @isherwood
in case we need 500 character to be sliced..
https://jsfiddle.net/edmyname/d9qpe8wz/2/